# Browser `paste` event with multiple files selection

Tags: javascript, dom-events, clipboard, copy-paste, clipboard-interaction

I'm having trouble with handling `paste` to browser, with multiple images clipboard. I'm using the following snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener('paste', event => {
  console.log(event.items)
})
```

It works if a single file was selected, showing 3 items, with the types of text/plain, text/html and image/png. However, if two or more files were selected then `clipboardData` only contains items with the type `text/plain` and `text/html`, as if a text was copied.

I also checked the `event.files`, for single file `event.files` contains that one file, however for multiple files the list was empty.

Last but not least, I also checked the newer API - `navigator.clipboard.read()`. It shows the correct number of items (same number with the files I copied), however I was not be able to extract the files from those items.

Any help?

Comment: did you find an answer?